# Replace function is replacing empty line in output. Please correct

Tags: powershell, replace

```
$SEL = Select-String -Path D:\PS\input.txt -Pattern "SyncIDE=1" | select-object -ExpandProperty Line
$file= 'D:\PS\input.txt'
$find= Select-String -Path D:\PS\input.txt -Pattern "SyncIDE=1" | select-object -ExpandProperty Line
  if ($SEL -ne $null)
  {
      $CharArray =$SEL.Split("=")
      $CharArray[1] += 1
      $final= write-host "$($Chararray[0])=$($charArray[1])"
      echo $final
      ECHO $find
     (Get-Content -path D:\PS\input.txt) -replace $find,'IDE=11' | Set-Content -Path D:\PS\output.txt
  }
  else
  {
    echo Not Contains String
 }
```

Im trying to find SyncIDE=0 word in a file and then add a prefix to the number after '=', if file contains SyncIDE=(anyinterger), then add interger 1 as prefix , SyncIDE=1(anyinteger). ex SyncIDE=0 then it should be SyncIDE=10.

I believe code upto some extent is right, but replace function is not working, please help.

Input file

AppRemote=\path_of_app_server\VG\Login\vg.exe
xxx
kdfk
SyncIDE=1
djhdk
SyncIDF=1
Test

Output file

AppRemote=\path_of_app_server\VG\Login\vg.exe
xxx
kdfk

djhdk
SyncIDF=1
Test

it is [image: input ouput]Replacing empty line instead of SyncIDE=11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in your code there are some misbehavings with what you're saying you are trying to achieve.
First - in code you are trying to find `SyncIDE=1` (in question you are saying you're looking for `SyncIDE=0`).

Then - you said you want to add a prefix, yet in code you are adding a suffix (`$CharArray[1] += 1`).

`Get-Content` returns an array of strings, so you have to act accordingly in your script - preferably iterate through it. Also - remember that `-replace` uses regex.

I refactored your code and came up with something like this:

```
$file= "C:\Temp\input.txt";
$outFile = 'C:\Temp\output.txt';
$pattern = "SyncIDE=1"
$find = Select-String -Path $file -Pattern $pattern | select-object -ExpandProperty Line;
$find = $find.Trim();
if ($null -ne $find)
{
    $CharArray = $find.Split("=");
    $final = "$($Chararray[0])=1$($charArray[1])";
    Write-Output "FINAL is $final";
    (Get-Content -path $file) | Foreach-Object {
        #iterating through all lines in file and replacing the content
        $_ -replace $find, $final;
    } | Set-Content -Path $outFile;
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Does not contain $pattern";
}
```

input:

```
AppRemote=\path_of_app_server\VG\Login\vg.exe 
xxx 
kdfk 
SyncIDE=1 
djhdk 
SyncIDF=1 
Test
```

output:

```
AppRemote=\path_of_app_server\VG\Login\vg.exe 
xxx 
kdfk 
SyncIDE=11 
djhdk 
SyncIDF=1 
Test
```